# Java.util.logger Keeps writing to a new log file

Tags: java, jsp, logging

I'm having this issue where my logger keeps writing to a new file

```
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NewLogger");
    FileHandler fh;
    //create log file string 
    Date date = new Date(); 
    String yyyyMMdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
    String logFileName = "retrieveproductstracking_" + yyyyMMdd; 
    fh = new FileHandler("./" + logFileName + ".log");
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);

    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    logger.info(request.getRemoteAddr() + ", " + url + ", " + "timestamp" );
```

This code is being used in a JSP where it's called and the logger logs the URL, IP. The problem is that the logger writes to a new file every time, but not only that...it writes to all of the previous files before it too.

Not exactly what I had in mind for rotating logs.

See image: http://puu.sh/cnu39/8b814e9f3f.png
http://puu.sh/cnvKw/8c0e5dce11.png

Comment: Do you have anything configured in an XML or properties file?

Comment: No. Besides the Tomcat stuff.

Comment: Added answer as requested!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to close the file handler with `fh.close()` once you've finished. Otherwise, you leave the files locked. That's why your image is showing so many lock files open!

Answer (score 2):

specify second argument to append to existing file.(open file in append mode)

```
 fh = new FileHandler("logFileName.log",true); // true specify append mode
```

Comment: Tried this, still getting the same result

Comment: it's because each time you are changing your file name.

Comment: can you expand on that? The file name is the same, but it automatically creates a new file and appends a number to the end of it.

Comment: since file name is getting changed so new file is created each time

Comment: But @user3724053 says all the old files are being written to as well!

Comment: I don't understand, the file names are the same. It creates a new file, with a new number appended to the end of it, and it writes to all of the previous files as well. Notice filename, and the size of the files. See images in the original post.

Comment: @chiastic-security as per the code above posted by user3724053 there is no way to that old file are also being written. there will be more code where they might be updating.

Comment: @chiastic-security check their image attachment each time an integer value is added to the end of file that means they might be updating some other place also.

Comment: I'm not updating it anywhere else. Everytime the JSP is opened, it does the code from above. I just don't understand why it makes a new file and writes to it, and all the previous files as well. Maybe I have to close the logger or something?

Comment: What on earth are all those lock files doing still there?

Comment: @chiastic-security ! thats it. I have to close the file handler so that it stop locking the file with fh.close(). Answer the question so I can give you some rep